# How do I change the SQL query on the basis of user input in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

This is my code where I am receiving the props from ui and it is a boolean value that I am receiving. From the UI, I'm passing true and false:

```
public void AlterTableColumn(int instanceid, bool IsHidden)
{
    var sqlQuery2 = String.Format("Update {0} set {1} = 1 where Id = {2};", "Mytable", "IsHidden", instanceid);

    string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"].ToString();
    // getConnectionStringById(instanceId.ToString());

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand sql_cmnd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, connection);
        sql_cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sql_cmnd.CommandTimeout = 10000;

        sql_cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sql_cmnd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

How do I change the `sqlQuery2` mentioned above in terms of true or false? Right now it is making 1 in the SQL table for true or false

Comment: convert the bool to int and use that value 0 or 1

Comment: Change your `1`  to reflect the value of `IsHidden`. Also you're using `IsHidden` as the column name you're wanting to update... FWIW use parameters, helps prevent SQLi and would make this query easier. Finally you added the `mysql` tag, it doesn't appear you are using `mysql` rather `sql`, please remove that tag if not applicable.

Comment: right now everything is 1 be it false or true , i just need condition for sqlQuery2

Comment: Use a parameterized query, set proper param values.

Comment: parameterized query as in ?

Comment: Be aware: your code is subject to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is written now, the value of `sqlQuery2` will be:

`Update Mytable set IsHidden = 1 where Id = /*the value of the passed in instanceId*/`

You're never using the passed in `bool`, `IsHidden`. You're always setting the `IsHidden` column to `1`, regardless of what you pass the `IsHidden` function parameter.

In order to update the database to `1` or `0` based on the `IsHidden` parameter you need to set an `int` based on the value of that parameter. You also need to update the query itself to use the `int` rather than always setting the value to `1`.

```cs
int isHiddenDbValue = IsHidden ? 1 : 0;
var sqlQuery2 = string.Format("Update {0} set IsHidden = {1} where Id = {2}",
   "Mytable", isHiddenDbValue, instanceId);
```

That being said, rather than using `string.Format` and putting the values in the query directly like you're doing, you should use a parameterized query. This will protect you from SQL injection attacks.

For example:

```
public void AlterTableColumn(int instanceid, bool IsHidden)
{
    int isHiddenDbValue = IsHidden ? 1 : 0;
    var sqlQuery2 = "Update Mytable set IsHidden = @IsHidden where Id = @Id";
    string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"].ToString();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand sql_cmnd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, connection);
        sql_cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sql_cmnd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
        sql_cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IsHidden", isHiddenDbValue);
        sql_cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", instanceId);
        sql_cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql_cmnd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```